# How overload resolution happens for two different template methods?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution

If I have the following template methods:

```
template< typename T >
void function( T a )
{
    cout<<"Template T"<<endl;
}

template< typename T >
void function( int a )
{
    cout<<"Function taking Int"<<endl;
}
```

On calling `function< float >( 2.5 )`, the second function gets called outputting: `Function taking Int`.

If I try to instantiate the functions for the float type, I get

> void function( float a );

And

> void function( int a );

From which the first one seems to be the better match for the double type( arg 2.5 ) that I am passing.

Then, why does the program chooses the second method?

Comment: `2.5` is a `double`. `double` to `float` and `double` to `int` are equally bad. Then...partial ordering kicks in and decides that the second is more specialized than the first, so that one gets called.

Comment: @T.C. Nice answer!

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @songyuanyao Nah, an actual answer would explain exactly how that partial ordering works. But the rules in this area have plenty of recent changes (some/most not yet implemented in any compiler) and I'm not exactly feeling like doing standard archaeology.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, the actual rule might be complex; it's still important to be aware that the partial ordering rule is taking effect here.